# Appending timer into <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

***Functionality:***

A timer will start counting from 0 seconds and value will increment every 1 second. The timer will continue to increment till it reaches 59 mins 59secs before the timer will stop.

***What has been done:***

I have set 2 different `<div>` that will dynamically display the timer value as it is increasing. 1st `<div>` is for the minute value while the 2nd `<div>` is for the second value.

While the timer increment is done a setinterval method of 1 second

***Issue:***

I have tried to append the value of timer to one of the `<div>` but realise that the minute value of the timer will not be able to be appended to the 1st `<div>` and the value will only be displayed in the 2nd `<div>`

Hence, I would like to ask for assistance on how to splice the value of the system timer such that the minute value can be appended and can be displayed in the 1st `<div>` when the second value can be appended and can be displayed in the 2nd `<div>`

***Code:***

```js
var GameTimer = 0;

$("#Game_Elements").fadeIn({
  queue: false,
  complete: function() {

    //Start Game Timer
    var SetGameTimer = setInterval(function() {

      GameTimer++;

      //append timer to timer game elements
      $("#Game_Minute_timer").html(GameTimer);
      $("#Game_Second_timer").html(GameTimer);

      //Check on time, if more than 1hr, automatically navigate to last game page

    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="Game_Elements" style="position:absolute; z-index:7; top:0px; left:0px; width: 1920px; heigth: 1000px; margin:auto;">
  <table id="Game_Timer_Element">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="Game_Minute_timer" style="z-index:50; position:absolute; top:609px; left:900px; font-size:90px; font-family:'GothicBold'; width:1080; color:#fff;">
          <font face="GothicBold"></font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="Game_Second_timer" style="z-index:50; position:absolute; top:609px; left:900px; font-size:90px; font-family:'GothicBold'; width:1080; color:#fff;">
          <font face="GothicBold"></font>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly - you need a timer counting each second till it reaches 59 minutes and 59 seconds and show the values of minutes and seconds somewhere?

Comment: @TomaszKajtoch Yes, that is correct. I already have the method of counting just that I am stuck in splicing the minute value out to append the values separately

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to put the time in one div and use Modulus/Math.floor to do your Minute:Second timer.

Like this:

```
$("#Game_timer").html(Math.floor(GameTimer / 60) + ":" + GameTimer % 60);
```

If you want to keep them in separate div's go ahead and stick with the same layout you had, and use

```
Math.Floor(GameTimer / 60)
```

for minutes, and

```
Gametimer % 60
```

for seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You have only seconds, so you have to split them to minutes and seconds. For example:

```js
var GameTimer = 0;

$("#Game_Elements").fadeIn({
  queue: false,
  complete: function() {
    //Start Game Timer
    var SetGameTimer = setInterval(function() {

      GameTimer++;
      
      var minutes = ('0' + Math.floor(GameTimer/ 60)).slice(-2);
      var seconds = ('0' + (GameTimer - minutes * 60)).slice(-2);
      if(minutes < 60){
          //append timer to timer game elements
          $("#Game_Minute_timer").html(minutes+" : ");
          $("#Game_Second_timer").html(seconds);
      }

      //Check on time, if more than 1hr, automatically navigate to last game page
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Game_Elements" style="">
  <table id="Game_Timer_Element">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="Game_Minute_timer" style="">
          <font face="GothicBold"></font>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="Game_Second_timer" style="">
          <font face="GothicBold"></font>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```